# Film - White rooms, some sort of tests

Tags: story-identification, movie

After watching *Divergent* and talking with some friends, I've linked it with another film, which I'm trying to recall. I clearly remember white rooms, lots of lights, some sort of tests (and there was a entry test, or meeting with doctors(?) maybe). The tests might be only for women and the main character might have blonde hair. I remember she was told by one of the testers or competitors that she isn't "compatible" for this programme and she would fail the real tests or that she wouldn't make something (the longer I think about it, it might be for some sort of space programme). I am certain that this film was made before 2014, maybe even 2010, but after 2000. This lab had futuristic glass screens.

I vaguely remember blue suits and that the tests were more mental than physical (if any). 
Any clues? I would love to watch that again.

Comment: Predestination? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVOpfpYijHA&feature=youtu.be&t=54s

Comment: The white room and the main protagonist being a woman reminds me of "The Killing Room" or "Breathing Room" (or a host of [other "isolation films"](http://horrornews.net/58067/top-15-group-isolation-horror-films/)), but they don't hit the other marks.

Comment: see OP confirmation comment for answer below

Answer (score 4):

This is [Predestination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film)). You can see the testing sequence in the clip below. The protagonist is in training so see if she's good enough to become a space-<s>whore</s> comfort-girl.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Yes, that was *Predestination*. Thank you very much.
Also thanks for correcting my mistakes.

Comment: @rimyi Please click on the checkmark on Valorum's answer to accept it. You can also leave a comment there. :)

Comment: @rimyi Ah. And it looks like you've accidentally created a second account. Please log into the account you wrote the question in. You can find information on retrieving the account [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account). You can also try merging the accounts as per [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: Smooth edit, Valorum. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Actually it was rather more accurate to begin with